# Selecting Customer with maximum orders

Tags: mysql

I have the following simple table:

```
CustomerID  CustomerName   NumOfOrders
1           Joe            15
2           Jane           20
7           Clara          1
```

I want to find the customer with maximum number of orders. Seems trivial enough but I can,t seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
ORDER BY
    NumOfOrders DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Very simple but effective :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, MAX(NumOfOrders) FROM myTable
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa021/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
select customername, sum(numOfOrders) as cnoo
from myTable
group by customername 
order by cnoo 
limit 1
```

and if customerName is unique (i.e. only one row per customer):

```
select customername
from myTable
order by numOfOrders desc
limit 1
```

Comment: +1 but for the first query where we assume that customer is not unique shouldn't you have `SUM(NumOfOrders)` and `GROUP BY customername` ?

Comment: @Stephan: yes, you're quite right. I've corrected it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CustomerID, NumOfOrders FROM myTable
where  NumOfOrders  =(select MAX(NumOfOrders) FROM myTable)
```

Comment: why do you need `MAX` in the main query ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
select top 1 customerName from customer_Order order by numOfOrders desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY NumOfOrders DESC LIMIT 1`